# How to activate the INavigationRoot interface when creating new members in plone site

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a Plone site which contains many users. I am trying to make the user folder look as autonomous as possible. I decided that the *collective.lineage* package is too much and I am trying to implement a much simpler solution. 
So whenever I create a new user, I go into the zmi and activate the following interface for the user's folder.

```
plone.app.layout.navigation.interfaces.INavigationRoot
```

This way the users have their own independent navigation bar. I am also using *collective.folderlogo* to let the users easily replace the plone site logo with their own.

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically activate the INavigationRoot interface whenever I create a new user.

Comment: You most likely can listen to a new member creation event and then mark the interface on the folder in your own addon code: http://developer.plone.org/components/interfaces.html#setting-dynamic-marker-interfaces-programmatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to listen to **IPrincipalCreatedEvent** from [Products.PluggableAuthService](https://github.com/do3cc/Products.PluggableAuthService/blob/master/Products/PluggableAuthService/interfaces/events.py); then you can mark the folder with **INavigationRoot** as Mikko suggested.